# Where can I get the Authorized User instance in a laravel api call?

Tags: php, laravel

When I use Laravel API endpoint controller, how do I get the user I loggedin on the same instance over a web controller?

Comment: is this API route defined in `routes/api.php`?

Comment: yes it is defined there

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what authentication package are you using, but generally you can just use this:

```
$user = Auth::user(); //user instance
$id = Auth::id(); //user id
```

Additionaly, when using POST request, you can use $request->user(), which will look like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user(); //returns an instance of the authenticated user...
}
```

Comment: that's fun. i tried that: does not work. what needs to be done that this works?